# Why I cant send a Gmail email with SwiftMailer?

Tags: symfony, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

When I try to send an email using `swiftmailer` in my Symfony project I get this exception:

> Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be
> established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

Here's my config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    encryption: '%mailer_encryption%'
    port: '%mailer_port%'
    auth_mode:  '%mailer_auth_mode%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
```

and my parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: pidev
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_encryption: ssl
    mailer_auth_mode: login
    mailer_port: 465
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user: 'myGmailAddress'
    mailer_password: 'mypassword'
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

I've allowed less secure apps on my Gmail account and disabled my antivirus and my firewall.
Also, I've already tried to ping smtp.gmail.com, it works fine but I got the same problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem resolved, I had just to add the two following code lines:

```
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
```

in

> ```
> vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
> ```

just after the line 263, so it will look like that:

```
$options = array_merge($options, $this->_params['stream_context_options']);
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
```

and now everything works fine!

Comment: Changing vendor code is never a solution. What do you think what happens to your code when you run a composer update?

Comment: For me, after commenting spool: { type: memory } , it worked

Answer (score 0):

Sending emails with gmail is pretty easy. Configure the following keys:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
```

and you are done !

Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/email/gmail.html

Comment: remove any  other configuration key that is not above.

Comment: Google can also block the access for security reason, you maybe have to allow the device (server). Look around https://myaccount.google.com/security